# Changing from http to https has meant redirects do not work

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

I have made my local development area https by adding the following to my httpd-xampp.conf to make all my pages https

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    #Redirect all to HTTPS
        RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</IfModule>
```

Anyway I have a redirect which means that when the user goes to the following page:

```
https://localhost/MYZone/project/public/index.php/store/randomproduct/
```

they are redirected to:

```
https://localhost/MYZone/project/public/index.php/store/randomproduct/randid_235dsgf3qdf
```

In the previous http version this worked fine, however, now it just continues to connect and in the google developer network just says pending and does nothing. I imagine this is something to do with apache config on xampp.

I have altered my code to redirect from

```
https://localhost/MYZone/project/public/index.php/store/
```

to

```
https://localhost/MYZone/project/public/index.php/store/randomproduct
```

And in chrome I can see that the randomproduct method is called and I debugged and I can see that store redirects properly redirects to the random product method and it is called but it just will not call a random product method with the ID as it issues the redirect and then chrome just sits there pending.

I have added a breakpoint at the start of my Codeigniter project on the index.php and it is just not started at all and I have no idea why?

Thanks

Comment: Just try this `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on` with the `=` sign. I'm not sure if both are valid.

Comment: No difference by changing that

Comment: randid_235dsgf3qdf is appended by your framework, not apache rewrite. You should check your codeigniter config first.

Comment: Would it be useful to show my .htaccess file?

Comment: Have to agree with jacouh, check your codeigniter configs first.